# Button disappears when object is deleted

Tags: python, add-on, panel

I have a panel button that disappears whenever an object (mesh, light, camera etc) is deleted
from the scene. Is there a fix for this?

```
@classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True


def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    obj = context.object
    row = layout.row()

    row.prop(context.object, 'lock_location', text = "", icon = "UNLOCKED", toggle = True)
```

I've also tried using a row.operator instead of a prop, this sort of works but I lose toggle ability. With my panel I'm trying to achieve something similar to the locks on the Properties panel. They don't disappear when an object is deleted:
[image: Properties]

Comment: The button disappears because the property it displays is attached to an object (`context.object`) and you've deleted that object.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks. Is there a way to change context or somehow keep the button visible regardless of the object being deleted?

Comment: How is supposed to work? If you have deleted the object, what object should be the active one? Select something and button will get back

Comment: @Crantisz I understand that the button will come back on selecting another object, but I'd like it to not disappear in the first place (see my response to Marty)

Comment: When you delete the object, you delete all of the data associated with it, including `lock_location`, so there's nothing available for Blender to display.  You would have to add a property that was attached to something other than `bpy.types.Object`, and use it as a cache, but may I ask what you're trying to accomplish?  Perhaps there's a better approach.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you, I edited my question in response to your request

Comment: The locks on the Transform display are icons that are generated by an `ICON=` argument to the prop display.  But you will notice that if there's no object the entire `Transform` subpanel disappears, so you have created a similar effect.

Comment: Aah you're right! Why on earth would it do that. I mean I sort of get why, but not from a UI usability standpoint. Ok, sounds like there's no easy way to bypass this

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the object, what object should be the active one? If you want, you can add a placeholder if the active object is not available:

```
if context.object is not None:
   row.prop(context.object, 'lock_location', text = "", icon = "UNLOCKED", toggle = True)
else: 
   row.label(text = 'Active object is not assigned')
```

Comment: You can leave `is not None` off of the if test. That's actually the preferred idiom. `bpy.context` instead of `context` in a draw routine is a bug.

Comment: It doesn't really matter on my end which object should be the active one, and it would be much better if the button was just greyed out instead of disappearing.